# SQL Server 2014 change license key

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, license

I need to change the Microsoft SQL Server 2014 license key (just key - not versions). I have found that it is possible via SQL Server Installation Wizard:

- http://www.alexandreviot.net/2015/11/10/sql-server-2014-how-to-change-the-product-key/
- http://www.sqlcoffee.com/SQLServer2012_0015.htm

Do I need to stop SQL services for that? Or will some downtime be needed? 
I think that when upgrade is clicked, SQL services will be restarted probably, right?

Answer (score 2):

I have been going through this exercise for a large amount of servers. I am not going to explain why I am doing this due privacy reason.

I will give you high level steps and let me know if this is not enough.

1. Get binaries for the version you want to change to.
2. Start setup.ext
3. Chose maintenance-->Edition upgrade
4. Follow standard installation process
5. If you have more than one instnace on a single host choose the
   intance you want to change key.
6. For me it normally takes about 5 minutes.
7. Will not ask for a recycle of SQL Server engine in most cases.Microsoft engineers recommend you do a recycle anyway.  You can stage the change before you schedule maintenance window to avoid an extra downtime.

Comment: >7. Will not ask for a recycle of SQL Server engine in most cases.Microsoft >engineers recommend you do a recycle anyway. You can stage the change before >you schedule maintenance window to avoid an extra downtime." I dont get point 7 - you mean that it does not need SQL server service restart, right ? But it is recommended to restart it ? Setup will change only licence key ? it will not make any changes for example in service starting parameters or any reinstall ? Do I need to make some database backup or all should go smooth ?

Comment: Please do not add your questions as another answer.  Yes recommended. Yes it will only change license key. I cannot guarantee on your last question, you should always have valid backup, despite you are making change or no. For me so far everything went smooth. I did about 8 servers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the license key. If Microsoft checks your licensing all they will check the number of servers/cores you are running SQL on and the number of licenses you have. The actual license can move from server to server, you can add more cores to a license and so on without re-installing.

Comment: The problem is that someone used wrong licence from other company ;-)

Comment: It doesn't matter. Microsoft doesn't care. They care that you have the license, that you have paid for it, not what key you used to install it